# Get progress status of a REST web service

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a web page that calls a REST web service to a Java remote server and I would like to get the progress of the process. I use jQuery ajax asynchronously to call my web service from my web page.
How can I achieve that?

my REST web service looks like this :

```java
    @PostMapping("/main/postData")
    public String postData(@RequestParam("values") String values)
    {
       //process data
       //update a global variable with status
    }
```

I have tried to create a variable in a Service class that is updated by my web service in various steps of the process. Then a second web service that returns the value of that variable. But how to call in a loop with Ajax that second web service at the exact same time as the first?

(I don't know if it's a good way, it was just an idea)

Comment: So, what happens if two users call `/main/postData` at the same time, considering you only have the single service property for progress keeping, by the looks?

Comment: You can use `request.getSession().setAttribute("values",value)` for store session data. If your process finished you can update attribute value.

Comment: @Eugen but how I can retrieve that value with ajax. I need to pool that variable while the web service is processing

Comment: You can create an interval function `setInterval` that runs as soon as the main API call is triggered and when main API call is complete, clear the interval  function`clearInterval`. The interval function should call the progress API to get the variable value at specific intervals. Well this assumes that the main API is slower and progress API is faster, else you wouldn't see any progress change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you've 2 end points, 1 to call the process and a second one to check the progress of the process. You need something like following:

```
var x = setInterval(() => {
    fetch('/progressOfProcess').then(function(result) {
        //log current progress
        console.log(result)
    })
}, 1000)

fetch('/yourMainProcess').then(function() {
    clearInterval(x)
})
```